# JPA 2.0 Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, constraints, foreign-key-relationship

I have simple OneToOne relationship:
*Data* <-> *TherapyResult*

I would like to express the following constraints
with JPA.

1. If a *Data* entity gets removed the associated *TherapyResult* should be delete,too
2. If a *TherapyResult* entity gets removed the associated *Data* entity should remain in the db

The first constraint is really easy with JPA as I can add *CascadingType.REMOVE*

```
@OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
private TherapyResult therapyResult;
```

For the second constraint I would like to add something like

```
@JoinColumn(columnDefinition = "DATA_ID BIGINT CONSTRAINT THERAPYRESULTDTAID FOREIGN KEY (DATA_ID) REFERENCES DATA (ID) ON DELETE SET NULL")
```

However this does not work. OpenJPA seems to have something similiar, but I want to use JPA 2.0 and EclipseLink. [OpenJPA ForeignKey](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.1/apache-openjpa-1.0.1/docs/manual/ref_guide_mapping_jpa.html#ref_guide_mapping_jpa_fk).

Another solution would be using *@PreRemove* [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380498/express-not-trivial-constraints-in-jpa), which works but looks a bit "none-best-practices" to me. However just a feeling.

My setup is:
Eclipse 3.7.1
EclipseLink 2.3
Apache Derby 10.8.3 and/or HSQLDB

any help is appreciated,
Muki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use pure JPA to specify foreign keys ... that spec doesn't include the ability. JDO is the only standard with the ability to define FKs. You have to use implementation specifics, or just define the schema yourself and let the JPA impl run on it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be valid since JPA 2.1: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/ForeignKey.html

Answer (score 2):

If you have a foreign key from Data to TherapyResult, and Data is the owner of the association, then

- removing the Data will delete the TherapyResult automatically if cascade is set to REMOVE
- you just need to set the `therapyResult` field to null and then delete the TherapyResult to have what you need. Another option is to set orphanRemoval to true, in which case setting the `therapyResult` field to null is sufficient to remove it from the database

If you have a foreign key from TherapyResult to Data, and TherapyResult is the owner of the association, then

- removing the Data will delete the TherapyResult automatically if cascade is set to REMOVE on the `Data.therapyResult` field.
- removing the TherapyResult will leave the Data in the DB provided the cascade is not set to REMOVE on the `TherapyResult.data` field

Comment: Nice, but what happens if the relationship is Many TherapyResult to One Data, and the foreignkey is from TherapyResult to Data? How is it possible to: removing TherapyResult does not remove Data; removing Data removes all related TherapyResults?

Comment: Removing the therapy will just do that. Removing the data will remove the therapy results if the associatio from data to therapy result has a REMOVE cascade. That's what a cascade on an association means: when doing X on entity, also do X on the associated entities.