# Implementation of LocalValidatorFactoryBean other than hibernate-validator?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

Do you know an implementation of springframework's `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` other than hibernate-validator?

We don't want hibernate-validator because it fetches too many dependencies in a small spring-mvc 3 application that doesn't use hibernate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384968/is-there-an-implementation-of-jsr-303-bean-validation-available has related info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't precisely answer you question with respect to other implementations of `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`, but what concerns the dependencies of Hibernate Validator, there are actually not that many.

The only strict dependency besides the JSR 303 API (validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar) is slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar plus a binding for it (here you could use the NOP binding for instance if you don't want to pull in a logger).

All the other dependencies are optional and can be left out depending on your setup/requirements (e.g. JAXB is only required when working with XML descriptors and running on JDK 5).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Raghuram, there is an [Apache Bean Validation](http://incubator.apache.org/bval/cwiki/index.html) (formerly agimatec) which seems to be [more efficient](http://carinae.net/2010/06/benchmarking-hibernate-validator-and-apache-beanvalidation-the-two-jsr-303-implementations/) than Hibernate one's.