# API for object validation in java

Tags: java, validation

I searching in web for find a validation framework at java. I found several choice such as:

- [iScreen](http://www.i-screen.org/)
- [Apache Common Validator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/)
- Spring Validation Framework (I don't known more about it)

All those framework have several benefits and options, also those cover my requirements.

My question is :
Is there any `API` for validation framework?

(I needed this requirement in 'Script Language Invocation' and solve by '[Apache BSF (Bean Scripting Framework)](http://commons.apache.org/bsf/)', it is an abstraction layer for invoking script in java)

I don't know about validation framework in java, if my question is wrong sorry.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Any validation framework will offer an API, how else would you use it? What exactly do you mean by API?

Comment: Yes,such as `Hibernate` and `JPA` relation, a interface collection and a implementation. I discuss `Apache BSF` for this reason.

Comment: Ah, you mean an *abstraction layer*? An API with *several* implementations from different vendors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bean validation API has been standardized through the Java Community Process as [JSR-303](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303), and included in the [Java EE 6 specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html).

About implementations see

[Is there an implementation of JSR-303 (bean validation) available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384968/is-there-an-implementation-of-jsr-303-bean-validation-available)

Answer (score 1):

I have always found OVal to be a very useful validation library - http://oval.sourceforge.net/