# @Valid working without spring-mvc?

Tags: spring, validation, wicket, javabeans

I'd like to use @Valid annotation to validate my beans in controller method. Unfortunatelly it does not work. I know that in order to make it work I'd have to include spring-mvc into my project and put there mvc:annotation-driven or @EnableMvc... .

But I do not use spring-mvc! I use Wicket framework. How to make @Valid working without incorporating spring-mvc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Valid is not specific to spring it is an implementation of [JSR 303 bean validation](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303). You can use any other reference implementation or write your own. e.g Apache and Hibernate Validator has reference implementation available. Take a look at this answer [Is there an implementation of JSR-303 (bean validation) available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384968/is-there-an-implementation-of-jsr-303-bean-validation-available)

Comment: I am aware of this. It's just I don't know what to do to get @Valid (on the controller methods, not inside a bean to be validated) annotation working. Hibernate validator is present in the classpath.