# How to send username and password in Ajax call?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

Here I want to send username and password to my spring mvc controller. I am using ajax to call mvc method.And it is not reaching to controller.

**angular controller:-**

```
$scope.formSubmit=function(){
        alert("submitted")

        return $http({
            url :'loginSubmit' ,
            method : "POST",
            data: { username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password }
            //data: data
        }).success(function(data, status, headers){

        }).error(function(data, status, headers) {
            console.log("login error"+status);     
     }); 

    }
```

**mvc controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/loginSubmit",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public  @ResponseBody User loadUserByUsername(@RequestParam("username") String username,@RequestParam("password") String password, HttpSession session){
        System.out.println("controller");
        System.out.println("name is "+username);

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Can you check the network in console and see where is your request hitting?

Comment: And then please log the requested url on the server side. ALWAYS send credentials in the body. [Read comments](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38716703/4723795)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using request params, you have to append to URL

```
$scope.formSubmit=function(){
        alert("submitted")

        return $http({
            url :'loginSubmit?username='+$scope.username+'&password='+$scope.password ,
            method : "POST",
        }).success(function(data, status, headers){

        }).error(function(data, status, headers) {
            console.log("login error"+status);     
     }); 

    }
```

**Note:** Dont use alert. Use console.log

The best way to do this would be sending the credentials in body instead of request URL

** Retain your old JS code of sending data as body and Change the JAVA code to**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/loginSubmit",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public  @ResponseBody User loadUserByUsername(@RequestBody Map<String,Object> credentials, HttpSession session){
    String username = credentials.get("username");
    String password = credentials.get("password");
    System.out.println("controller");
    System.out.println("name is "+username);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: And then please log the requested url on the server side. ALWAYS send credentials in the body. [Some discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38716703/4723795)

Comment: It's not nessesary when you use Spring Security. Then, if you send body as a form, Spring will resolve on itself. It's explained in attached post

Comment: @xenteros may I know In Map<String,Object> , What is string and Object

Comment: `String` is a key. For example "username" and "password". `Object` will be a value. e.g. "mypassword" or 123 for an id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$scope.formSubmit=function(){
        alert("submitted")
        var uname = $scope.username,pswd=$scope.password;
        return $http({
            url :'loginSubmit',
            method : "POST",
            params : {username:uname,password:pswd}
        }).success(function(data, status, headers){

        }).error(function(data, status, headers) {
            console.log("login error"+status);     
     }); 

    }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
return $http({
            url :'/loginSubmit',
            method : "POST",
            data: { username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password }
            //data: data
        }).success(function(data, status, headers){

        }).error(function(data, status, headers) {
            console.log("login error"+status);     
     }); 

    }

@RequestMapping(value="/loginSubmit",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public  @ResponseBody User loadUserByUsername(@RequestParam("username") String username,@RequestParam("password") String password, HttpSession session){
        System.out.println("controller");
        System.out.println("name is "+username);

        return null;
    }
```