# Configure Spring Security to accept login details from POST body instead of request params

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am building a `rest` application using Spring boot and Spring security. In the login module I want my code to read username and password, sent from a client, from Post body. But my code reads only from the url, like `Get` request.

I tried to make a request from the Postman. Set the method as `Post`. When i set the username and password in the request param field. I get the "200 ok", but when I send the parameters as json in Post request, I get `401 unauthorized`. What configuration changes do I need to make?

my Spring security config:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
                authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("Admin")
                .antMatchers("/db").hasAuthority("DBA")
                .antMatchers("/user").hasAuthority("USER").anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureHandler(customFailureHandler)
                .successHandler(customSuccessHandler)
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }
```

Comment: please check this one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716703/how-do-i-disable-resolving-login-parameters-passed-as-url-parameters-from-the)

Comment: genrally we configure Login Post method to read user-pass and authenticate the user.But here I have no where configured the Login Post method as Spring Security internally handles it. Do i need to provide custom Login Post?