# Why is Java saying I can't use @NotBlank with a string

Tags: java

I have the following code

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
...
@NotBlank(message="Not Blank")
private String thing;
```

When I try to run I get

> No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank' validating type 'java.lang.String'

How do I use NotBlank annotation with a string?

*Java 8*

Comment: is it Spring annotation? `import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;` I can only see javax... has NotNull other than NotBlank

Comment: My guess is that you're using an old version of something (maybe your validator?) that doesn't know about the standardized annotation yet. Post your POM/Gradle file.

Comment: This validation is part of JEE, not JSE.  Are you using EE?

Comment: As far as I know I am the container is SpringBoot and Tomcat

Answer (score 3):

The `javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank` annotation you are applying is part of `Bean Validation API v2`.

The most probable case is:

- You have bean validation API v2 as dependency on your project
- The implementing framework/library supports only v1.0/v1.1 API.

Please check on this post for information about existing implementations: [Is there JSR-303 implementation available?](https://www.google.by/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384968/is-there-an-implementation-of-jsr-303-bean-validation-available&ved=0ahUKEwia0LXS1O_XAhXPzaQKHcNLANQQFggbMAA&usg=AOvVaw0PuXdnFtMY06DiFDuYXFIL)

I recommend you checking for bean validation API v2 on your classpath (it also can be called JSR-380). The only implementation of this API I know about is Hibernate Validator v6.0. Make sure that v2 implementation is not hidden by some v1.x implementation being on classpath.

Comment: Sure I will try to add some of the dependencies I think might matter. What libraries would have API v1 as a dependency? Spring, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem and solved it. Because the validation version conflicts,
In my project, the error was introduced twice validate。check the jar package, and then remove, then successful。

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```