# how to assert that a field is not present in a JSON Object

Tags: java, json, assert

If you have a JSON Object (in Java) with multiple nested fields, how do you assert that a specific field is not present?

e.g. For the following object below, how would you assert that field C does/does not exist:

```
{
"A": {
       "B": {
           "C": "field exists"
       }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an idea.
you can bind the json to a java object using any libraries such as jackson. 
the object class you could add bean validation annotations like @NonNull etc .
then you can obtain a bean validator object and call validate on the java object. this will give you a set of errors .

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html

also there are 2 libraries that implements jsr 303

[Is there an implementation of JSR-303 (bean validation) available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384968/is-there-an-implementation-of-jsr-303-bean-validation-available)

a small tutorial is availabe here
https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation

Answer (score 0):

For unit testing with java and json I use the [hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/) library and one of it extension [json-path-assert](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/tree/master/json-path-assert).

This let me assert using [json-path](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) expressions.

Assert that C does exist

```java
assertThat(yourJsonString, hasJsonPath("$.*.*.C"));
```

Assert than C doesn't exist

```java
assertThat(yourJsonString, hasNoJsonPath("$.*.*.C"));
```