# Is there a C#(.net) equivalent of JSR 303/349

Tags: c#, .net, validation

I am new to C# (.net) , i am trying to see if there is a standard way to validate the inputs for a REST API call.

Like in Java World we have JSR 303 / 349 Is there a C#(.net) equivalent of JSR 303/349 ?

Mostly all Java framework have some sort of similar framework [Is there an implementation of JSR-303 (bean validation) available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384968/is-there-an-implementation-of-jsr-303-bean-validation-available)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an implementation of JSR-303 (bean validation) available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384968/is-there-an-implementation-of-jsr-303-bean-validation-available)

Comment: @cemahseri I expect the OP wants a .Net implementation of the link that was already known

Comment: @cemahseri this link does not help, i am looking for corresponding C# solution the link you shared is java only solution